# Is a declaration valid inside an if block with no actual block?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Is the following code valid? If so, what is the scope of `x`?

```
int main()
{
   if (true) int x = 42;
}
```

My intuition says that there is no scope created by the `if` because no actual block (`{}`) follows it.

Comment: Hm, my intuition is that the scope doesn't depend on the {} being present, or in other words that for a single statement the presence of { } is optional.

Comment: It should only exist for the scope of conditional, single statements don't require the `{}`.

Comment: @NicholasSmith But can you _prove_ it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797810/why-are-my-structs-members-not-properly-initialised-using#comment20723793_14797810

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: sure, I could link to your frankly excellent answer, or dig through the C++ language specification to find where it talks about scope definition and block definition.

Comment: @NicholasSmith: Rhetorical ;)

Comment: I actually do this quite often, to create a line I can stick a breakpoint on. Of course you need to put the statement on a different line to the `if`.

Comment: @JackAidley Why not put a breakpoint on an actual line of real code?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Because I don't necessarily want to break on a real line of code. For example, I might want to break into a loop when `foo[i]==356`; adding two lines of code going `if (foo[i]==256) int spug=7;` (it's always `spug=7`, I don't know why) let's me break when into a complex loop at the point I want.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

GCC 4.7.2 shows us that, while the code is *valid*, [the scope of `x` is still simply the conditional](https://ideone.com/MOnO5C).

#### Scope

This is due to:

> `[C++11: 6.4/1]:` *[..]* The substatement in a *selection-statement* (each substatement, in the `else` form of the `if` statement) implicitly defines a block scope. *[..]*

Consequently, your code is equivalent to the following:

```
int main()
{
   if (true) {
      int x = 42;
   }
}
```

#### Validity

It's *valid* in terms of the grammar because the production for selection statements is thus (by `[C++11: 6.4/1]`):

> *selection-statement*:
>     **`if` ( *condition* ) *statement***
>     `if` ( *condition* ) *statement* `else` *statement*
>     `switch` ( *condition* ) *statement*

and `int x = 42;` is a *statement* (by `[C++11: 6/1]`):

> *statement*:
>     *labeled-statement*
>     *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *expression-statement*
>     *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *compound-statement*
>     *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *selection-statement*
>     *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *iteration-statement*
>     *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *jump-statement*
>     ***declaration-statement***
>     *attribute-specifier-seq*<sub>opt</sub> *try-block*

Answer (score 2):

My Visual studio says that time of life of your variable x is pretty small - 
just while we are inside operator if,
so x vill be destroyed when we are out of if condition, and there is absolutely no meaning to 
declare variables like this.

Comment: Your English is fine, btw.

Comment: What if the variable constructor has side effects? (I know, I am being picky, but *there is absolutely no meaning* is not 100% correct)

Comment: no "side effects" are being shoun by VS, just that the variable x is being destroyed after we exit "if"

Comment: No, you didn't understand @Anton. Here we are constructing `int`, but if I, did, for example `if(cond) ObjWithSideEffectsCtor o;` it would matter.

Comment: Or, for example, if you did chaining, like `new internetAPIhandlerobject().sendAPImessage("some message")`;