# Sharing access to member variable from multiple classes

Tags: c++, oop

Consider the following example

```
class GameObject {
  vec3 position;
  SphereCollider collider;
  // ...
};

SphereCollider* GameObject::getCollider(){
  return &collider;
}


class SphereCollider {
  vec3 position;
  float radius;
};
```

You can notice that in this design there is a duplicity of a member variable `position` shared among more classes. The `radius` is there to show there can be other data members.

The SphereCollider is later used for collision detection and I have more classes of GameObject (with no common ancestor) which compose the SphereCollider.

What is the cleanest way to handle this situation design and performance wise? Is there a convention in this?

There are few solutions in my mind, but none of them is perfect. Can you think of a better solution?

**1) Persistent data member access via getter/setter**

Cons: No direct access to the data member inside the class. Is there a convention to tell this truth to the programmer who will further work on this class?

```
void GameObject::setPosition(vec3& pos){
  position = pos;
  colliser->setPosition(pos);
}

vec3 GameObject::getPosition(){
  return position;
}
```

**2) Remove redundancy and use getter/setter access to the SphereCollider**

Cons: similar to 1)

```
class GameObject {
  SphereCollider collider;
};

void GameObject::setPosition(vec3& pos){
  colliser->setPosition(pos);
}
```

**3) Reference/pointer from SphereCollider to GameObject data members**

Cons: Reallocating (e.g. std::vector) the GameObject may cause troubles. Is there a way of telling the user of this class?

```
class GameObject {
  vec3 position;
  SphereCollider collider;
public:
  GameObject(){
    collider = SphereCollider(position);
  }
};

class SphereCollider {
  const vec3& position;
  float radius;
public:
  Collider(vec3& pos)
    : position(pos)
  {
  }
};
```

**4) Propagate data to the SphereCollider on demand**

Cons: User can store the reference to the collider an skip using getCollider();

```
SphereCollider* GameObject::getCollider(){
  collider->setPosition(position);
  return &collider;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Said that the particular choice may depend on various more general design factors, I would prefer your option **(3)**. You can easily solve the problem with vector resizing by defining the proper *move constructor* of `GameObject`: it will be invoked when needed.

See these question/answers for example:

[Why does resize() cause a copy, rather than a move, of a vector's content when capacity is exceeded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730992/why-does-resize-cause-a-copy-rather-than-a-move-of-a-vectors-content-when-c)

[How to enforce move semantics when a vector grows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001823/how-to-enforce-move-semantics-when-a-vector-grows)