# Assigning elements in an array

Tags: c++, pointers

The following code allocates a 10 element array of pointers to doubles.

```
int i=0;

double* dp[10];


for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    *(dp[i]) = 0.0;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    cout<< *dp[i]<< endl;
}
```

Now how do I initialize each of these doubles to 0.0.

Comment: They aren't `double`s as you said they are pointer to `double`s and you can't initialize them to 0.0 but rather `nullptr`.

Comment: You need to write a loop that allocates space for each double, and initializes it.

Comment: You'll benefit greatly from using `std::vector` and/or `std::array`.

Comment: When I modify the code as above I end up with a segmentation fault -11. Anyone can explain me why. Carry on with your down votes, but I need to understand the concept.

Comment: Why do you think you need any array of *pointers*?

Answer (score 1):

Write a loop that allocates space for each double and initializes it:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    dp[i] = new double;
    *(dp[i]) = 0.0;
};
```

Are you sure you really need an array of pointers, not just an array of doubles? The latter would be simpler:

```
double dp[10] = {};
```

The empty initializer list defaults all the elements to `0.0`.

Comment: Why not just `std::vector<double> v(10, 0.0);` or   `std::array<double, 10> arr {0.0};`?

Comment: Because his question was about an array of pointers to doubles, not `std::vector`.

Comment: Without seeing the whole of his application, I can't comment on whether he really needs to indirect through pointers. So I just answered the question as asked.

Comment: Fair enough, but IMHO all she/he wants to do is to allocate an array of 10 `double`s.

Comment: [`double dp[10] = {0.0};` is misleading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14797812/560648). Prefer `double dp[10] = {};`

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I had the same misunderstanding as that questioner.

Answer (score -1):

Example with std::vector:

```
std::vector<double*> myArray(10);
std::fill(myArray.begin(), myArray.end(), new double(0.0));
```

(prefer classes from STL instead of C-style array in C++)

Comment: Every element will be the same, probably not what the OP is looking for. something like `std::vector<std::vector<double>>(10, std::vector<double>(1, 0.0))` would be more idiomatic and closer to what the OP wants.

Comment: Or even `std::vector<std::array<1, double>>(10, {0.0})`