# Using while / do-while loops for array element setting

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

I'm having some trouble understanding how to use a while loop to get the same results as this for loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
    int datum[i] = 0;
}
```

Basically, to set all the elements in the array datum[N] to 0.
Does the following code make sense in that regard, or am I missing something?  thanks

```
int i = 0;
while (i < N){
    datum[i] = 0;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: No you're not :) But for the first loop, why `int`? You can't redeclare `datum[i]`.

Comment: Initialize them to zero with `int datum[N] = {0};` would be better practice generally.

Comment: @ScottStainton: [`int datum[N] = {}` makes more logical sense](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14797810/560648) in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two code examples produce the same results.

```
int i = 0;
while (i < N)
{
     datum[i] = 0;
     i++;
}
```

---

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) 
{
   datum[i] = 0; // remove int because you will be redclaring datum
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use either of them. When you declare `datum`, do so like this:

```
std::vector<int> datum(N);
```

Done.