# Semantic of `string.length()`?

Tags: c++

I want to convert a char buffer of known size (e.g. received from socket) into a string, but
with the caveat that the char array is not necessarily null-terminated.

So I tried to use `string (InputIterator first, InputIterator last)` constructor.
However, 
I notice that `string::length()` isn't always the same as `strlen`,
at least in my case where strings are manually crafted from buffers 
with many trailing zeros.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char a[20] {0};

    a[0] = 'a';
    string b(a, a + 20);
    cout << b.length() << endl;
    cout << strlen(b.c_str()) << endl;
}
```

Output is

```
20
1
```

Though this is a well-defined behavior for `string::length` (thanks to the comments and some initial answers for helping me to realize that), I'd like to find a better / more idiomatic solution.

Comment: I believe you are flirting with disaster if the array is not null terminated.

Comment: You told it to start from `a+0` all the way to `a+20`, so it did that, nulls and all.

Comment: If the char array is not null-terminated, and you don't already know the length, that's a bug. There's nothing you can do, with or without `std::string`, to recover from that. You need one or the other.

Comment: @AndyG well I just want to find the cleanest way to convert a (say) 32-byte char array to a string. Of course I can manually add a `\0` to terminate it. But string constructor is cleaner, no? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MooingDuck To be precise, I know the length. That's why I can say `a+20`.

Comment: @qweruiop: No, that's not the length. The length is 1.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition well, define the length. `string::length` is a length but it's 20.

Comment: @qweruiop: The entire premise of this question is that you are personally defining the [desired] length as 1, and are displeased when the program tells you 20 instead. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I don't think I define the length anywhere, did I? To the contrary, I'm confused by what length means. That's why I asked.

Comment: Well then you are going to have to explain what you mean by _"transform a char[] into a string"_. If you don't want this example to result in a string of length 1, and you don't want this example to result in a string of length 20, then I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: @Ðаn One of them is mine. I thought I understood the question. Indeed the OP calls my solution "perfect". Yet these comments are now casting doubt on all that.

Answer (score 3):

The difference here is that, for a `std::string`, those NULL characters don't affect its length; it can hold them just fine.

However, for a c-style string, `strlen` with stop counting when it encounters the first NULL character, which for you is the second character, hence a size of 1.

Comment: @qweruiop: Yes. There's no requirement that `string::length` behave like `strlen` on the underlying array (In fact, it would probably be a bug if it did)

Answer (score 2):

You told it you wanted 20 bytes, so that's exactly what you got.

It sounds like you want to copy *up to 20 bytes or until a null byte is encountered*:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char a[20]{};

    a[0] = 'a';
    std::string b(a, a + strnlen(a, sizeof(a)));
    std::cout << b.length() << '\n';
    std::cout << strlen(b.c_str()) << '\n';
}
```

You'll notice I've gone back to having the computer detect the number of input bytes for us, but with `strnlen` you can tell it to stop at 20, taking care of the problem that the array *may* not be null-terminated.

I've also changed `{0}` to `{}`, for [style/sanity reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14797810/560648).

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f3edbc1d12f955bd))

Comment: @qweruiop: Don't know why you were surprised at the outcome then :P

Comment: I was surprised because `string::length` has a different semantic than `strlen`. That's somewhat counter-intuitive to me but it also makes sense after I know it.

Comment: C and C++ are different things, so it stands to reason that their string types work differently. In fact, C++ _having_ a string type and logical semantics that make sense is one of the main points of C++ over C. C's vulnerability to null nonsense is a limitation with which we are no longer encumbered.

Comment: I think I was just hoping to find a cleaner constructor.

Comment: Is there a problem with this one?

Comment: (other than my haphazard application of `std::` :$)

Comment: No this is a perfect solution. It would be nicer if the (non-existent) constructor could call `strnlen` and do all you wrote here in one line, no?

Comment: @qweruiop: I can see why you think that, but actually no. You're coming at this from the specific point of view of "I want C-like null-terminating behaviour", which is fine, but that is not the general case. In general, we do not concern ourselves with null-termination any more, in a string constructor or otherwise. A `std::string` is a sequence of bytes, nulls or otherwise. So it doesn't really make sense for that type to treat nulls specially by default.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144009/discussion-between-qweruiop-and-boundaryimposition).

Comment: Basically, forcing `std::string` to have your C mindset is bad, and encouraging you to lose your C mindset is good. :) And with that I'm off.