# Weird behavior when assigning one char array to another char array using char

Tags: c++, arrays

When I try to copy one element from char array to a char and then from same char to another char array, second char array gives weird output, usually containing whole string from first char array. This happens only when second char array is not initialized. My question is how char is able to transfer whole string to another char array.

```
int main()
{
    char a[10] = "ababababa";
    char b[5];
    char temp;

    temp=a[1];
    b[0]=temp;

    std::cout<<b;

}
```

While using g++ I get `b{�Uarabababa`
While using clang++ I get `b�U`

Content between `b` and `U` changes every time program is run.

Comment: If you want to use C-style strings, make sure to nul-terminate them correctly or weird things will ensue.

Comment: Try to initialize `b` with zeroes: `char b[5] = { 0 };`, your current code has undefined behavior, because a terminating NUL character is expected for `b`.

Comment: Is it possible that while outputting array ```b``` it somehow also outputs array ```a```. Because I tried this after initializing array ```b```, it gives proper output

Comment: @PK2n *undefined behaviour* makes almost everything possible.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ https://stackoverflow.com/q/14797810/560648

Comment: @Light Oh, good to know.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I believe you could use std::fill instead, if I'm not utterly mistaken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do C++ class members get initialized if I don't do it explicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127454/how-do-c-class-members-get-initialized-if-i-dont-do-it-explicitly)

Comment: @Chipster For initialisation, `= {}` is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char b[5];
```

Here, `b` is an array of `5`, *uninitialised* `char`s. Inspecting their values before initialising them results in *undefined behaviour*.

```
temp=a[1];
b[0]=temp;
```

Here, you <strike>*initialise*</strike> assign only to the first element of `b`. The rest are *still* uninitialised.

```
std::cout<<b;
```

Here, you use `b` as an array that is interpreted as a c-string by `std::cout` due to array decaying (effectively, `std::cout` sees `const char*`, which, by default, is assumed to be a null-terminated c-string). Since it requires inspecting the values of all the elements inside up to the null-terminator, it does so, which invokes *undefined bahaviour*, because some of the values are uninitialised.

A program that invokes undefined bahaviour cannot have its outcome predicted. Literally anything can happen, which includes different behaviours on different compilers or even different behaviours between executions.

Comment: Thank you, it explained the situation.

Comment: That is not initialisation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I suppose you mean the part where I said that "*Here, you **initialise** only the first element of `b`*" - correct, it's an assignemnt, not an initialisation.

Comment: That's right. "Initialising them" !== "giving them values" (though it is one way of doing so)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit corrected the post, thank you for your being vigilant.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was read a 2-3 days ago about constructors and we can make a constructor using ```initializer_list``` which allows ```={}``` initialization. So it is called initialization or assignment?

Comment: @Pk2n you are looking for distinguishment between copy-initialisation and direct / uniform initialisation. I recommend reading further about them.

Comment: @Fureeish in the book it was stated that "```=``` before ```{}```" is optional. So I am confused same style of assignment is in copy constructor section of book. Here I am assuming that assignment and initialization is same, assigning given value to object.

Comment: Assigning and initialising is not the same. However, `T t = {}` and `T t{}` most of the time are treated the same, they are not exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I'll read further.

Comment: @PK2n The key point you may be getting confused about is that in a declaration, the initialiser is sometimes preceded by a `=`. Like `int x = 42;`. However, unlike other uses of `=`, this is _not_ assignment! Yes, it's confusing. Both of Fureeish's examples in that comment are initialisation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So use of ```=``` during initialization is more like special case for ```=```. From limitation of my knowledge, I am assuming that initialization and assignment is basically giving value to the object but during initializing you are provided with the constructor to help you give proper value to object, which basically decrease chance of error.

Comment: @PK2n More or less yes

Answer (score 0):

The characters in `b` are uninitialised, they are therefore unlikely to contain a null character. You initialise the first character to `'b'` and then print the array.

The `char *` stream operator is invoked which determines the length of the string by scanning through it until it finds a null character. As the array doesn't contain a null character it keeps reading past the end of the array until it happens to find a null character somewhere else. In your case it looks like your compiler has stored `a` after `b` in the stack so it prints all the elements of `b`, some other character (perhaps `b` is padded up to an even number of bytes in memory) then the contents of `a`, stopping at the null terminator at the end of `a`. None of this is guaranteed and will change between compilers, operating systems and even different runs of your program. Welcome to the world of undefined behaviour.

The simple fix is to initialise `b` to all zeros at the beginning of your program:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char a[10] = "ababababa";
    char b[5];
    std::fill(std::begin(b), std::end(b), '\0');
    char temp;

    temp=a[1];
    b[0]=temp;

    std::cout<<b;

}
```

Alternatively avoid the problem completely with `std::string`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string a = "ababababa";
    std::string b( 1, a[ 0 ] );

    std::cout<<b;

}
```

Comment: I started using ```std::string``` in my project, after I had issues with char array. ```std::string``` is less pain to handle.